# Running this code results in unexpected outputs, can anyone explain what went wrong here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization

Whenever I run this, I get drastically unexpected results from my output after inputting each value. The results are massive negative numbers, numbers using exponents, and generally wrong outputs. My string array also doesn't seem to be called properly, instead, it is showing me a string of numbers and letters rather than the list of values it contains.

Here are the final outputs,

Jars sold last month for 012FF9B0 is:012FF928

High is -1

Low is -2147483648

Total is -858993460

Average is -1.22713e+08

I'm pretty new to c++ still, so any help is appreciated. If anyone can tell me why the final results are so strange, it would mean a lot. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{




string salsas[7] = { "mild", "medium", "hot", "sweet", "fruit", "verde", "zesty" };
{

    int num[7];
    int sum = 0;
    int HSP = -1;
    int low = 101;
    double sales[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        const int sales_type = 7;
        int num_sales[sales_type];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Mild Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[0];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Medium Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[1];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Hot Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[2];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Sweet Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[3];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Fruit Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[4];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Verde Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[5];

        cout << "Please enter amount of Zesty Salsa sold: ";
        cin >> num_sales[6];
        cout << endl;

        sum = sum + num[I];

        if (sales[i] > HSP)

            HSP = sales[I];


        if (sales[i] < low)

            low = sales[I];

        cout << "Jars sold last month for " << salsas << " is:" << sales << endl;

        double average = sum / 7;
        cout << "High is " << HSP << endl;
        cout << "Low is " << low << endl;
        cout << "Total is " << sum << endl;
        cout << "Average is " << average << endl;
        system("pause");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the program using a debugger. At what point does the behavior you expect to see diverge from the behavior you observe?

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation. I get lost again and again trying to read your code. Is supect you have at least one pair of unneeded `{}`.

Comment: Is there as special reason for your different identifiers `i` and `I`?

Comment: The more I study the shown code the more I suspect that it cannot be the one which is compiled and has the described behaviour. Please double-check and make sure you have provided a [mre].

Comment: You’re leaving both `num` and `sales` uninitialised, but use the values in them.

Comment: You seem to also confuse `sales` and `num_sales`. If there is intention explain it. But in any case make sure that you initialise `sales` before you read from it. I think it is uninitialilsed.

Comment: What you describe cannot be reproduced. With a lot of guessing the shown code can be turned into code which is likely to behave as bad as you describe. Fix it by cleaning up. Until then the question is either non-reproducable or lacks debugging. Each of that would be a reason to close it until it has been improved.

Comment: `sum / 7` is an *integer* operation, with an integer result. That you then initialize a floating-point variable with that integer result doesn't matter, the result won't be getting its fractions back.

Answer (score 0):

```
salsas
```

You decide to print this, but salsas is an array not one item, hence it prints out the memory address of the first element in the array....

```
double sales[7];
```

You declared a sales array but you never intialized any values in the array....

```
if (sales[i] > HSP)

            HSP = sales[I];
```

So this behavior is undefined you never know if it will execute or not, because you did not intialize sales[i], it could be purple for all you know.....

Same thing for:

```
if (sales[i] < low)

            low = sales[I];
```

As for sum:

```
sum = sum + num[I];
```

C++ is case sensitive i != I the array does not know what index capital I is ..... For the last part again you need to define your variables.
I don't know if you are from Java or python but C++ does not intialize your variables to anything, so no default values, if you did not intialize your variables the value of that variable is undefined, which means you dont know what the value is....